# Try to put a title on a table column in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I can't seem to add the title `Bonus %` to the 5th column, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code, I have tried to add the title the way I did for the other columns but it won't work.

```php
<?php


for($i=0; $i<33; $i++) {
   $staff[$i][0] = $i + 1;   
   $staff[$i][1] = rand(100000, 600000);  
   $staff[$i][2] = rand(14000, 40000);
   $staff[$i][4] = rand(1,7);

   if (rand(14000, 40000) >= 20000)
    $staff[$i][3] = "yes"; 
else
    $staff[$i][3] = "no";
}

print "<table border=1><tr><th>" . "Number of Staff" . "</th><th>" . "Staff Number" . "</th><th>"  . "Salary" . "</th><th>" . "Bonus?" . "</th></tr>". "Bonus %" . "</th></tr>";  

for($j=0; $j<33; $j++) {        
    print "<tr>";


          for ($k=0; $k<5; $k++) {   
            print "<td>" . $staff[$j][$k] . "</td>";

    }
    print "</tr>";
}


print "</table>"

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You table header `th` formatting is not correct. Can try like below. Also missing a terminating semi clone `;` at last line `print "</table>"`.

```
print "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>" . "Number of Staff" . "</th>
        <th>" . "Staff Number" . "</th>
        <th>"  . "Salary" . "</th>
        <th>" . "Bonus?" . "</th>
        <th>". "Bonus %" . "</th>
    </tr>
";

for($j=0; $j<33; $j++) {
    print "<tr>";
    for ($k=0; $k<5; $k++) {
        print "<td>" . $staff[$j][$k] . "</td>";
    }
    print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: Look at my answer to see your initial error on your code but this answer is 100% correct to, +1

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
"</th></tr>". "Bonus %" . "</th></tr>"
```

By

```
"</th><th>". "Bonus %" . "</th></tr>"
```

You close tr before end of line